# ContentProvider и отправка одного notifyChange для группы правок данных

Tags: android, многопоточность, contentprovider

Сделал приложение, которое использует `ContentProvider` и `ContentObserver` для работы с данными. В `ContentProvider` при обновлении данных вызывается `notifyChange`, который, в свою очередь, отлавливается обсервером и приводит к обновлению списка на экране.

Проблема в том, что данные у меня отправляются пачками (через `contentResolver.applyBatch`). Т.е. на несколько вызовов update у провайдера мне нужно делать только одно обновление данных на экране.

Насколько я понимаю, на уровне `ContentProvider` этого не сделать (по факту `applyBatch` отправляет `notifyChange` на каждое обновление в базе), т.к. это логика более высокого уровня. Хотя и не уверен в этом - возможно, в `ContentProvider` можно как-то определять что данная операция последняя в пачке?

Может быть кто-то с таким сталкивался и у него есть работающая схема?

Дополнение:

Обнаружил, что в `ContentProvider` есть метод `applyBatch`, который можно перекрыть.

Получился вот такой вариант с некоторой, на мой взгляд, топорной защитой (по идее, тут надо `мьютекс` использовать?):

```
static int batchDeep = 0;

@Override
public ContentProviderResult[]applyBatch(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations)  
                                                  throws OperationApplicationException {
    try {
        batchDeep++;
        return super.applyBatch(operations);

    } finally {
        batchDeep--;
        if (batchDeep == 0)
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(URI_INDEX, null);
    }
};
```

И в методах, обновляющих данные:

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String s, String[] selectionArgs) {
    ...
    if (batchDeep == 0)
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    ...
}
```

Теоретически, этот код, вроде-бы, делает то, что нужно. Но нет-ли здесь каких-то подводных камней, связанных с параллельным исполнением?

Answer (score 3):

`ContentProvider` заботиться как раз о таких подводных камнях, что и делает его привлекательным, подробнее [ContentProvider android doc.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html?hl=ru)